# Volume integral of a gradient

Tags: integration, volume

Assuming we have a scalar function f which tends to 0 at the boundary of a space. Is it true that the volume integral of the gradient of f will also tend to 0?

Answer (score 8):

You know the Gauss' divergence theorem says that
$\int_V \nabla \cdot \vec{A} \rm dV = \int_S \vec{A} \cdot d \vec{S}$

Now taking $\vec{A}= f \hat{c}$, where $\hat{c}$ is a constant vector, you can prove:

$\int_V (\nabla f)\rm dV = \int_S f d \vec{S}$

Now telling f tends zero on the surface will not be sufficient to say that left hand side is zero. **You have to say how it tends to zero on the surface**.

say your f=$\frac{1}{r}$, then obviously as r$\rightarrow \infty$, f$\rightarrow 0$

but$ \int_S f d \vec{S}$=$ \int_S \frac{1}{r}\hat{r} r^2 \sin (\theta) d\theta d\phi=r \int_S \hat{r} \sin (\theta) d\theta d\phi $ =$r \times 0$

now see you can't say $r \times 0=0$ when r$\rightarrow \infty$. (Also I have assumed perfectly spherical surface so that you can take out r out of the integral. But for any arbitrary surface r=$r(\theta)$. )

so if f decreases faster than $\frac{1}{r^2}$ then only you can say $\int_V (\nabla f)\rm dV $=0

Comment: I am not sure your answer is relevant: in your first formula, you have an integral of divergence in the left-hand side, not an integral of gradient.

Comment: @akhmeteli, as the first formula is true for any arbitrary vector, you can take that as $\vec{A}=f \vec{c}$. From that you will get the second formula. By the way this is a well known formula. You can find it in Griffiths' electrodynamics book too.

Comment: I stand corrected on this point.

Comment: Is the gradient of a scalar ever to be integrated over a volume?

Answer (score 1):

Provided the function is smooth enough, I'd say yes: the volume integral of its gradient is a vector that has three components; to calculate, say, the first component, you can integrate the derivative with respect to $x$ over $x$ first and, taking into account the boundary conditions, obtain zero.

EDIT (7/9/2014): I guess some extra conditions may be necessary to ensure that the relevant multiple integrals can be computed using iterated integrals (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem ).